# What are the differences between the Console and PC versions of Cities Skylines?

Tags: version-differences, cities-skylines

What are the differences between the Xbox One, PS4 and Nintendo Switch versions of Cities: Skylines and the PC Release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All content and features of all versions of the game are exactly the same apart from the fact you can have Mods on the PC version, and obviously at a higher resolution and frame rate also. But it depends on your play-style, if I had the choice, I'd pick PC.